# How to implement "if" without "else" in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to implement List.map on a list of integers, and I have an if statement checking to see if the given integer meets a specified requirement. If the requirement is satisfied I add the integer to the new list. However, because OCaml requires an else statement if the return type is not a unit, I am forced to add something even if the requirement is not satisfied.

Does anyone know of a way to avoid this, or another suitable approach?

Thank you!

```
let (--) i j = 
    let rec aux n acc =
      if n < i then acc else aux (n-1) (n :: acc)
    in aux j [] ;;

let generatePossibilities(currSum) =
    let allPossibilities = 0--100 in
    List.map (fun x -> if ((currSum + x) <= 100) then x else ("I don't want to do anything else")) allPossibilities
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, both branches of the `if` expression shall return a value, because all OCaml expressions must evaluate to a value.

The `List.map` function is an injective transformation, i.e., for each value in the input list, there is a corresponding value in the output list -- a one to one transformation. If you want to remove some of the elements, then you're looking for the `List.filter_map` it has type `('a -> 'b option) -> 'a list -> 'b list` so the filter function may return `None` (the functional representation of an absence of a value) if you don't want to map the value, otherwise it shall return `Some x`, e.g.,

```
List.filter_map (fun x -> if currSum + x <= 100 then Some x else None)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Please note, there is one situation where you can have `if` without `else`. If the expression returns `unit` it doesn't need an `else`. So something like `if some_condition then print_endline "blah"` is valid.